# How to Test if C# ref Arguments Reference the Same Item

Tags: c#

In C# given a function with the below signature

```
public static void Foo(ref int x, ref int y)
```

If the function was called using

```
int A = 10;
Foo(ref A, ref A)
```

Inside the function Foo is it possible to test that the x and y arguments reference the same variable? A simple equivalent test of x and y isn't sufficient as this is also true in the case two different variable have the same value.

Comment: What is your underlying problem? If the aliasing is causing problems then just operate on copies and update the parameters as the final step. The copies won't be aliases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to use unsafe code, you can compare the underlying variable addresses:

```
public static bool Foo(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* pa = &a, pb = &b)
        {
            // return true iff a and b are references to the same variable
            return pa == pb; 
        }
    }
}
```

(Edited to remove `unsafe` from method signature, based on @Michael Graczyk's comment.)

Comment: IMO this is the correct way to do it unless you *absolutely* cannot compile with `/unsafe`. Also drf `Foo` does not need to be unsafe because neither its return value nor any of its formals are unsafe types.

Comment: You can put the `fixed` block inside an `unsafe` block.

Comment: @Michael Graczyk I updated the answer so the method is not declared as unsafe.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)` to determine whether `x` and `y` were references to the same object.

Edit: As was pointed out by Kirk Woll (confirmed in this article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)), this method doesn't work for value types (due to boxing). You can get around this by changing the parameter types on the method from `int` to `object` (of course, this means you will also have to pass an `object` variable to the method - this can still be an `int`, though).

i.e. the method becomes:

```
public static void Foo(ref object x, ref object y) {
    Console.WriteLine("x and y the same ref: {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y));
}
```

and calling it with:

```
object A = 10;
Foo(ref A, ref A);
```

will result in `"x and y are the same ref: True"`

Comment: This will return false even if they are referencing the same variable.  (reference equality is meaningless for ints and other primitives)

Comment: From MSDN: "Object.ReferenceEquals always returns false for value types" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183759.aspx

Comment: This will return false positives. Consider: `object a = new object(); object b = a; Foo(ref a, ref b);` This claims that x and y are the same ref, but they are not.